# why run "python run_squad.py" doesn't work?

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I want fine tune on squad with huggingface run_squad.py, but meet the following question:

1, when I use "--do_train" without "True" as following code, after 20 minutes runing,there is no models in output_dir:

```
!python run_squad.py  \
    --model_type bert   \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased  \
    --output_dir models/bert/ \
    --data_dir data/squad   \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --overwrite_cache \
    --do_train  \
    --train_file train-v2.0.json   \
    --version_2_with_negative \
    --do_lower_case  \
    --do_eval   \
    --predict_file dev-v2.0.json   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 2   \
    --learning_rate 3e-5   \
    --num_train_epochs 2.0   \
    --max_seq_length 384   \
    --doc_stride 128   \
    --threads 10   \
    --save_steps 5000
```

2, when I use "--do_train=True" as following code, the error message is "run_squad.py: error: argument --do_train: ignored explicit argument 'True'":

```
!python run_squad.py  \
    --model_type bert   \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased  \
    --output_dir models/bert/ \
    --data_dir data/squad   \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --overwrite_cache \
    --do_train=True  \
    --train_file train-v2.0.json   \
    --version_2_with_negative \
    --do_lower_case  \
    --do_eval   \
    --predict_file dev-v2.0.json   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 2   \
    --learning_rate 3e-5   \
    --num_train_epochs 2.0   \
    --max_seq_length 384   \
    --doc_stride 128   \
    --threads 10   \
    --save_steps 5000
```

3, when I use "--do_train True" as following code, the error message is "run_squad.py: error: unrecognized arguments: True":

```
!python run_squad.py  \
    --model_type bert   \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased  \
    --output_dir models/bert/ \
    --data_dir data/squad   \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --overwrite_cache \
    --do_train True  \
    --train_file train-v2.0.json   \
    --version_2_with_negative \
    --do_lower_case  \
    --do_eval   \
    --predict_file dev-v2.0.json   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 2   \
    --learning_rate 3e-5   \
    --num_train_epochs 2.0   \
    --max_seq_length 384   \
    --doc_stride 128   \
    --threads 10   \
    --save_steps 5000
```

I run code in colab with GPU: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB

Judging by the running time, I think the code didn't through training process, but I don't know how to set parameters in order to let training go.what should I do?

Comment: What is in the output_dir? Which version of transformers do you use? Please ignore the options 2 and 3, they are completely wrong.

Comment: output_dir should be the models after training,but now, there is not even a output_dir directory. transformers is the newest because i use "pip install transformer"

Comment: I assume the last message you see is `tcmalloc ....` and is casued by colab as described [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4668). I don't know if you could ever execute run_squad.py on colab, but maybe one of the previous versions will work for you.

Comment: thanks, but sadly, I found old version has been deleted on huggingface

Comment: They use github and the previous versions are still there. Just click on the branch button and change the version tag. I think the directory structure was different in the past.